# Flags against "improve your accept rate" comments are failing

Tags: bug, status-completed, accept-rate, comment-flags

This evening, I happened across one of the more useless varieties of "improve your accept rate" comments. Actually, that's all it was: "Improve your accept rate". I flagged the comment as "not constructive / off-topic" (I hate, hate, *hate* these kinds of comments. New users have no idea, on the whole, what to do with them. A comment with a link to a discussion on the topic, *go here to learn more*, or a little explanation in the comment itself, sure, but a bare four words... *moving on*).

I've seen these comments disappear when I've flagged like this before. Sometimes they don't - I figure there's a wording difference. This time, though, I saw something unexpected:

> [image]

(that's not actually the comment I flagged initially. I went hunting for a comment without upvotes, in case that was contributing to the problem. It wasn't, apparently)

It sure looks like some part of SO seized on my flag and tried to delete the comment, but got hung up on something. The flag icon disappeared from that comment after that, and didn't reappear on refresh.

I hunted down another flag-worthy comment that didn't contain an accept-rate complaint (harder than I expected):

> [image]

Flagging as "not constructive" worked just fine here, and as expected, the comment wasn't deleted.

Comment: Works on my machine!  ;)

Comment: Said the person with the ♦ next to his name... Not sure if serious, but I reprod a third time, from IE this time.

Comment: Yeah, I was just teasing.  I'm sure the diamond is what's interfering with me reproducing what you're seeing.

Comment: The system is fighting back and sick of us being sick of them

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, your diamond saved you (because you always have comment deletion permissions and thus passed the check I mention in my answer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We recently moved some permissions checks around in preparation for a project that may still be a secret (I'm not sure). It has to do with API write access. Don't tell anyone.

When the comment flagging reaches a threshold, this will cause the comment to be deleted. However, the newly-hardened permission check would now fail in this case, because the current user usually *doesn't have* the permission to delete the comment.

A fix for this is being deployed right now.

Comment: I'll keep it between you and me, balpha.