# Detect images with white edges and automatically give them a border

Tags: feature-request, design, images

Images with white backgrounds often blur into the post. When the image itself contains text, this makes it difficult to see where the image ends and the next part of the post's text begins. People have complained about this problem before (e.g. [How to add border around images in a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202696/how-to-add-border-around-images-in-a-post) and [Add an option to include a drop shadow to images posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119014/add-an-option-to-include-a-drop-shadow-to-images-posted)).

A proposal: can't the system simply check each image that gets added to see if over 50% of either its top or bottom border is white (or is sufficiently close to the background colour of the site, in the case of any SE sites without white backgrounds), and if so, add a 1px black border automatically via CSS? This seems to solve the problem simply and in a visually clean way, without requiring any extra UI elements or giving the user adding the image the opportunity to screw up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not think that this is a good idea for pretty much the same reasons as forcing an automated spellcheck onto every post:

1. Adding an image to a post that has the problems you mention, is the poster’s fault. Not only is adding a border to the original image rather easy; there are also [some ways to avoid the problem in the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202696/255554). So, posting an image in a way that it suffers from these problems is like writing a post without bothering about spelling or formatting at all. So, what you are proposing is mainly helping the lazy.
2. This would be arguably not much easier to implement than [giving the user the option to add a border](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119014/255554).
3. There are many many images around, that your proposal would automatically fit with a border and that would not benefit from it. Two examples with added border:

[image]
[image]

Here are the questions containing those images and some more examples of images that would be detected by your algorithm, if their background were white instead of transparent (which would not make any difference to their final appearance): [1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37676/19174), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1371/308), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141493/36360).

Comment: "Arguably not much easier to implement?" I think this would be much harder to implement.

Comment: @Scimonster: The suggestion or the alternative?

Comment: The suggestion is a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Scimonster: I guess so too, but *not much easier* suffices for this argument.