# Removing a revision from a question causes the tags and the title to be removed

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

I edited [How is it possible that a single user who is not a moderator can delete a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196435/how-is-it-possible-that-a-single-user-who-is-not-a-moderator-can-delete-a-commen) after an image was removed from the question, since the question without image was not that much clear.

When I tried to save it after editing it, I could not continue since:

- The tags were gone

  [image: screenshot]
- The title followed the tags

  (Sorry, I didn't think to take a screenshot.)

As you can see from [the revision page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/196435/revisions), it results that title and the tags were added in the second revision, when they were clearly present since the first revision, as it is not possible to post a question without title and tags.

[image: screenshot]