# Allow moderators to undelete the comments deleted after being flagged by a single user

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

See [How is it possible that a single user who is not a moderator can delete a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196435/how-is-it-possible-that-a-single-user-who-is-not-a-moderator-can-delete-a-commen) for more details.
In short, two comments have been probably deleted after a single user flagged them as obsolete because they contained *accept* or *accepting* in a sentence.

I found out that, as moderator, I cannot undelete those comments for which the deletion threshold is lowered to 1 flag.

[image: screeshot]

Since on *Drupal Answers* users could ask a question about a module for accepting answers, the word *accept* could be contained in a comment, even though the comment is not saying anything about the user not accepting answers given to his questions. For example, the comment could be "What is your module supposed to do when you accept your own answer?" or "You can accept your own answer, and the module doesn't consider that possibility!"
In that case, a single user who flags the comment as obsolete would cause the deletion of the comment, even if the comment is not obsolete at all. As moderator, I cannot do anything to reverse that.

Moderators should be able to undelete those comments for which the system decides they can be deleted after being flagged from a single user.

Comment: I agree. There are a few places where the word "accept" can be used in a non-answer-accepting context.

Comment: Can you undelete comments deleted by other moderator? It's also one-user-deletion which is not the comment author.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, I can, as long as the deleted comment is not for a deleted post.

Comment: Personally I think this one is a bug then.

Comment: yeah; if this deletion was attributed to Community rather than the last flagger, the problem would go away.

Comment: @Shog9 So you mean, the check to see if moderators are unable to undelete a comment is if the comment's deletion was attributed to a non-mod user?

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog I guess the code just checks if the user to whom the deletion is attributed is a non-moderator. It should check if the user to whom is attributed the deletion is the user who posted the comment. It's expected that moderators cannot undelete comments deleted by the users who posted them.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Has anyone on the team picked this up?

Answer (score 5):

There is at least a work around for this. Samliew's ModUserscripts repo has a [CommentUndeleter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#comment-undeleter-) script that should allow mods to restore these sorts of comments. It would obviously be preferable if this was a standard feature, but most mods seem to be pretty receptive to using userscripts on the site.

Comment: Moderators can undelete any comment as a stock part of the user interface. However, the ability to do so is on the page listing all of a user's comments, not on question pages.