# Single Flag deletes comment with profanity

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

There is an existing question [How is it possible that a single user who is not a moderator can delete a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196435) 4 years old about a post a year prior, that focuses on a post containing the word(s) 'accept', 'accepted' and/or 'accepting' I do not believe this is the same.

I am a 10k+ user on a beta site, saw a new post that was not a good fit, down voted it, voted to close and left a comment while the view count was at 2.  I moved on.

[Link to post in question at outdoors.stackexchange.com](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18084/making-a-workshop-casey-neistat-style)
[image]

The OP posted a comment and I came back when I got the notification.  The comment contained profanity and I flagged it as Rude, and the comment instantly disappeared (screen shot above is after it disappeared)

I looked at the [Privileges page](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) and it does not seem to be a documented feature.

How did a non-admin delete a comment with a single flag?

Comment: @gparyani I don't think it is a duplicate of that question.  Your poroposed dupe is related to the "accept" filter I mention in the opening paragraph.  The answer below by  'ArtOfCode' with the related link seems to address the question clearly.  While the second answer on you proposed duplicate does have an answer by 'Jeff Atwood' that hints at the same, it is not clear.

Comment: That is linked from the comment flagging FAQ, under "comments containing certain keywords can reduce this amount".

Comment: @gparyani, I agree with James here. The two questions are totally different, and although Jeff's answer hints at the answer to this question,  it is by not means clear. Most importantly, people looking for the info _this_ question is seeking are not very likely to pick up that other thread, or if they do, think it relevant.

Comment: @Who: That's what closing as duplicate is for. It's to point this people to that question, for searchability. It's not a negative marking against this question, as downvoting and closing as other reasons are.

Comment: Also, it's common here on MSE to close questions as duplicates if the answers are similar, even though the questions are merely related.

Comment: @gparyani, I know what marking as duplicate is for. I just think that the other thread is _less_ relevant, so directing people over there is not the best idea. This thread is already more helpful than the other one IMO.

Comment: @gparyani Being common and being good policy are two different things. Personally, I don't like the practice at all and would much rather we only close based on questions, not answers.

Comment: @catija I agree with that. Marking the _question_ as a duplicate when it just has a duplicate _answer_ doesn't make sense to me. It marks the wrong post as duplicate, and I don't see any reason for pointing out duplicate answers  anyway.

Comment: @kiamlaluno why did you reopen? The answer is given in those other questions as well.

Comment: There was, at some point, an answer where someone did some comprehensive testing to figure out what the exact triggers were, and posted an answer here about it. Where did that go?

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. There is, somewhere in the SE software, a blacklist of keywords - if a comment contains one of these keywords, any flag on the comment will delete it. It's only tangentially related, but [Community deletion of comments should raise a moderator flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284053/community-deletion-of-comments-should-raise-a-moderator-flag) contains some details on how this system operates.