# Reopening a question isn't clearing its duplicates list

Tags: feature-request, bug, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Moderators and gold tag users can [edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links). This was done [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305223/single-flag-deletes-comment-with-profanity), for example.

All good so far.

However, when a question that was closed as duplicate and its duplicates list has been edited is reopened, the duplicates list is not cleared. This means that if the question is then closed again as a duplicate, it will show the list of duplicates instead of starting from a clean slate.

This can be seen in the [revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/305223/revisions) of the above question:

> [image: revisions of the questions]

And then the question is closed as duplicate of all those in the list:

> [image: list of duplicates question is actually closed as]

In this specific case I agreed with the original closure so the list is still good, but in other cases, question might be wrongly closed as duplicate of other questions, reopened, closed as duplicate of the actual source, but still be duplicate of that wrong list of questions.

I really think that reopening should clear that list.